# Picasso cannot resolve method 'With(android.content.Context)'

Tags: android, picasso

I am getting the error cannot resolve method 'With(android.content.Context)'

If you know what the issue is and how I may be able to resolve this that would be great thanks.

I do have the Picasso dependency in my Gradle file already.

```
Picasso.With(cart.getBaseContext())
              .load(listData.get(position).getImage())
              .resize(70, 70)
              .centerCrop()
              .into(holder.cart_image);
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation, `with(android.content.Context)` method got deleted and you have to use the new APIs. It's just `Picasso.get()` now!

```
Picasso.get()
   .load(listData.get(position).getImage())
   .resize(70, 70)
   .centerCrop()
   .into(holder.cart_image);
```

Take a look at the changes that were made in this diff https://github.com/square/picasso/compare/picasso-parent-2.5.2...2.71828